# What is the maximum length in seconds to store a value in memcache

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

The [Google App Engine memcache documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass.html#Client_set) states that the `time` parameter of `memcache.set()` is an "Optional expiration time, either relative number of seconds from current time (up to 1 month), or an absolute Unix epoch time."

So I tried to set a value for 30 days, which [according to Google](http://www.google.com/#q=30+days+in+seconds) is 2 592 000 seconds.

However, I highly suspect that this value is too high, because the value was set (`memcache.set()` returned the value `True`), but a `memcache.get()` just after always returned `None`. Reducing this value to [1 728 000 seconds](http://www.google.com/#q=20+days+in+seconds) just worked fine/as expected.

I guess that once passed the highest value, the `time` parameter gets interpreted as an absolute Unix epoch time. That would mean that 2 592 000 seconds got interpreted as "Sat, 31 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", which is obviously a date in the past...

So **what is the highest value** you can enter that will get interpreted as a number of seconds in the future?

Edit: On the local dev server, 2 592 000 second worked OK, but not on the production servers. I suppose both servers have a different interpretation of the values.

Comment: Since you're getting different behaviour on the dev server and in prod, could you please file a bug in the issue tracker to this effect?

Answer (score 3):

Your linked Google documentation is oddly imprecise; the actual [memcached documentation](http://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) is more specific, saying the number may not *exceed* 2,592,000 (30 days of seconds). So in theory, that should have worked, barring implementation issues. (That statement is echoed in the PHP [documentation for its memcache stuff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memcache-add.php).) So according to the memcached docs, your first value should have worked.

I don't suppose 2,591,999 works? The Google doc does say "*up to* one month", which if you assume 30 days in a month (not a valid assumption) would be *up to* 2,592,000 (e.g., but not including). That's at odds with the memcached docs, but perhaps there's an implementation difference or something.